# How to modify the BFS algorithm to find the shortest distance

Tags: graph-algorithm

Suppose in a graph , all edges have the same weight=1. Explain how you would modify the BFS algorithm to find the shortest distance,SD, from A to B , that is on a call SD ( A,B), where A is the starting vertex and B is ending vertex. Consider all the possible answers to the SD problem.

Comment: There are several songs on the internet with the title: 'think for yourself' - especially one from the Beatles or some lyrics from Tool. Of course in these days they should be rewritten: 'google for yourself'. Keep rocking!

Answer (score 2):

BFS as is can give you the shortest distance between A and B assuming A and B are on the same connected graph.

Usually, BFS takes on a starting node then discover its neighborhood one level at a time, meaning it discovers all the nodes at distance 1, then all nodes at distance 2 and so on.

Let's call the new version of BFS that returns the SD from A to B: BFS_D

So the first modification would be to give it two parameters instead of one. The return type of BFS_D would become a boolean.

Now we have two possibilities: either there is a path from A to B or there isn't.

If there is a path, at some point, we are going to get B from the node queue. We can use a second queue to store the level of each node and thus, we can find the distance of A to B.

If there is no path, we will simply discover all the connected graph containing A without finding B. Basically, once we have no more nodes to visit, we just return false or Inifinity.

A third case can happen which is where A == B, we must make sure that our code handles correctly this case.

Here's a simple implementation of the modified BFS based on the [wikipedia code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search):

```
procedure BFS_D(G,A,B):
      create a queue Q // This will store the undiscovered nodes
      create a queue D // This will store the level (distance) of each node
      enqueue A onto Q
      enqueue 0 onto D
      mark A
      while Q is not empty:
          t ← Q.dequeue()
          td ← D.dequeue()
          if t is equal to B:
              return td
          for all edges e in G.incidentEdges(t) do
              // G.opposite returns adjacent vertex 
             o ← G.opposite(t,e)
             if o is not marked:
                  mark o
                  enqueue o onto Q
                  enqueue (td + 1) onto D
      return Infinity // We have discovered all the nodes without find B, there is no path
```